# Image in the interface is not updated after WritableBitmap has changed

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, writablebitmap

I am trying to update the image by drawing circles every time mouse pointer is moved. The pixelBuffer is stored in `map` object and updated with `CircleFilledWithGradientMethod()`. I load the pixel buffer in to `WriteableBitmap Bitmap` and then try to display it by setting image source of an image element in my XAML UI to Bitmap. What happens, is that when I first move my mouse, I see the very first 2 circles drawn but then as I move the mouse, the image does not get updated. Why could that be? Is there a method I should call on `Image` to force it to redraw? The reason I use `stream.WriteAsync` two times, when I could have just used it one, is just to show that it is working properly.

```
  private async void TextArea_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                Pixel pixel1 = new Pixel(255, 0, 0);
                Pixel pixel2 = new Pixel(255, 255, 255);

                map.CircleFilledWithGradient((int) pointer.Position.X, (int)pointer.Position.Y, 100, pixel1, pixel2);

                using (Stream stream = Bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
                {
                    stream.WriteAsync(map.pixelData, 0, map.pixelData.Length);
                }
                map.CircleFilledWithGradient((int)pointer.Position.X+100, (int)pointer.Position.Y, 100, pixel1, pixel2);

                using (Stream stream = Bitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
                {
                    stream.WriteAsync(map.pixelData, 0, map.pixelData.Length);
                }
                this.Image.Source = Bitmap;
            }
```

What I think is happening, is that as soon as I draw the image on the screen, it caches it, and then keeps using the old image. Or is it that the standard Image element does not support redrawing?

Update: 
My `Bitmap` was a private class variable. If I do

```
WriteableBitmap Bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.Grid.RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight);
```

It all starts to work, but isn't that memory inefficient? Aren't I allocating memory for each new `WriteableBitmap` each time I move my mouse. And as I have found out, the issue is definitely with with Image component. Why wouldn't it update when I just make changes to it's source, but updates when I change its source to a different object.
`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a method I should call on Image to force it to redraw?

Close. There's a method on WriteableBitmap.

Call [WriteableBitmap.Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.invalidate.aspx) after you update it to request the refresh.

Assuming the Bitmap was already set as Image.Source, replace the line:

```
 this.Image.Source = Bitmap;
```

With:

```
 Bitmap.Invalidate();
```

> Why wouldn't it update when I just make changes to its source, but updates when I change its source to a different object.

Setting the Image.Source to the same thing it's already set to is a noop. Most complex Properties ignore "changes" which don't change the existing value. Creating a new WriteableBitmap each time works (very inefficiently) because it's different.

Comment: So there is nothing like InvalidateRegion of Win32? If I wanna draw 1 pixel, do I need to redraw the whole image? That seem pretty inefficient.

Comment: For more efficient immediate mode rendering use Win2D instead of WriteableBitmap. https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D