# Can WriteableBitmap only be written-to once?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, uwp, win-universal-app

I'm setting an `Image`'s `Source` to a `WriteableBitmap`, and I'm populating that `WriteableBitmap` using its `PixelBuffer`. The first time I write to it, it works. But subsequent writes are ignored. Why?

I'm using:

```
Stream s = myWriteableBitmap.PixelBuffer.AsStream()
```

(it's in a `using`. and I'm not getting any exceptions)

Comment: Have you tried [to call *Invalidate* on your bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40407297/2681948)?

Comment: @Romasz Perfect! You can transform that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Rob Claplan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40407297/2681948) you should call [Invalidate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.invalidate.aspx) after performing changes to your *Bitmap*.